# Number of real solution of a trig equation.

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

> Q.$$\text{Let, } \arctan x \in{\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{2}\right)}, \text{ for } x \in \mathbb{R}\\\text{Then the number of real solutions of the equation}\\
> \sqrt{1 + \cos(2x)} = \sqrt{2}{\arctan(\tan x)} 
> \text{ in the set } 
> \\\left(-\frac{3\pi}{2}, -\frac{\pi}{2} \right) \cup \left(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right) \cup \left(\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{3\pi}{2}\right)$$

The expression can be simplified to,
$$|\cos x|=\arctan (\tan x)$$

Case I, $x\in\left(-\frac{3\pi}{2}, -\frac{\pi}{2} \right)$,

$$-\cos x=x+\pi\tag {i}$$

Case II, $x\in\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$,

$$\cos x=x \tag {ii}$$

Case III, $x\in\left(\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{3\pi}{2}\right)$,

$$-\cos x=x-\pi \tag {iii}$$

We, can easily comment on (ii), it has one unique real solution. But,commenting on  (i) and (iii) is tricky. By, graphical analysis I found that they has also one unique solution.

[image]

This question is from a comparative exam. So, for exam point of view I am finding an alternative   approach.

Thanks for giving your valuable time.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @jjagmath alternative approach where we don't need a graphical calculator .

Comment: You could begin by observing that both $\sqrt{1 + \cos(2x)}$ and  $\sqrt{2}{\arctan(\tan x)} $ are periodic with period $\pi$ so you only need to find the number of solutions in the interval $(-\tfrac{\pi}{2}, \tfrac{\pi}{2})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\cos(x+\pi)=-\cos (x) = \cos(x-\pi) $

Thus, (i) can be rewritten as, $\;\;\cos(x+\pi)=x+\pi\;\;$ for $x\in\left(-\frac{3\pi}{2}, -\frac{\pi}{2} \right)$; 
which can be transformed to
$\;\;\cos(y)=y\;\;$ for $y\in\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2} \right)$

This is the same as (ii) in terms of number of solutions. similarly for (iii).

You can easily graph $\cos(x)$ vs $x$ in $\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2} \right)$. In this interval, when $x<0$, $\cos(x)>0>x$ - so no intersections.
When $x>0$, $\cos(x)$ is strictly decreasing and $x$ is strictly increasing - so at most one solution - which there indeed is.

Comment: I have overlooked the periodic nature of the function.